# I want to make an 'if' statement that if a variable is less the 80 t=0 but if the variable is over t=x-80

Tags: c++

hi i just started to learn c++. I'm trying to figure out how to make a variable change depending on another variable. It shows a strange answer when i try it idk where its getting it from. anyways i'll just put my code in here and hope someone understands what i am doing.

```
#include <iostream>

long int mult (float hours,float payrate,float tax,float overtimerate,float overtimehours,float overtimeday,float insurance);

int main()
{
float insurance;
float hours;
float payrate;
float tax;
float overtimerate;
float overtimehours;
float overtimeday;
insurance=.81;
overtimehours=0;
overtimerate=1.5;
tax=4.93372123545367;
   std::cout<<"Paycheck calculator\n";
   std::cout<<"Enter your hours\n";
   std::cin>>hours;
   std::cin.ignore();
   std::cout<<"Did you work over 8 hours in a day?\n If so enter how much? If none enter 0\n";
   std::cin>>overtimeday;
 if  (hours>80)
{
overtimehours=((hours - 80)+overtimeday);
   }
   std::cout<<overtimehours+overtimeday<<"\n";
   std::cout<<"Enter your pay rate\n";
   std::cin>>payrate;
   std::cin.ignore();
   std::cout<<"Your paycheck should be approximately: "<<((overtimeday+overtimehours)*(overtimerate*payrate
))+(((hours-overtimehours)*payrate)-((((hours-(overtimeday+overtimehours))*payrate)/tax)
-insurance))<<"\n";
}
```

Comment: Please use more descriptive variable names than x, t, w, and z

Comment: Also, what are you entering, and what is the strange answer?

Comment: i am entering my hours 80 and also entering my payrate 17 and getting an outcome of my paycheck=net pay

Answer (score 9):

In the expression:

`x=(t*w)+((hours-t)*rate);`

You are using `t`, even though `t` has never been set.
`t` will be undefined at this point, and may have any value.

Same thing with `hours` and `rate`.

Your compiler should have given you warnings about uninitialized variables.

**Edit** looking at your code more, it seems you are attempting to establish "rules" for hour, rate and t, then later fill in the values, expecting those "rules" will be preserved.

C++ does **not** work like this.  It is a sequential language, meaning that each instruction is executed once, as it is read, top-to-bottom.

You need to change your program flow to be:

1. Gather variables
2. Do calculations and logic
3. Output the answers.

It seems you reversed steps 1 and 2, trying to setup the calculations before gathering the variables.

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign a value to `t` before using it.  Saying `float t;` will not actually give it a meaningful value.  Ditto `hours` and `rate`.  Assign them **before** doing `x=(t*w)+((hours-t)*rate);`.

Answer (score 2):

you haven't initialized hours (it is always good practice to initialize all your local variables)

note also that 'hours' is of type float and these are not represented exactly so your compare with 80 may yield a different result than you expected.

Answer (score 1):

I see you have a function declared:

```
int mult (float x,float t,float w,float hours, float rate,float z);
```

that you never do anything with. I think the code you have in `main` mostly belongs in `mult` and that your main should either assign values to these variables or prompt the user for them and read them from `cin`. You do this for some variables later on, but then never use what you read in.

I agree with @quantumSoup btw, your variables are poorly named. Also, your code is really in an odd order. This makes it hard to guess what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers pointed out very serious flaws in your code, so you should take them seriously, but there is one thing, the topic suggests you are struggling with, that wasn't explained. Let me try.

I think you are struggling with a way to calculate `overtime`. You take an input from a user, that indicates the number of `hours` of work. If that number is less or equal to `80`, there is no overtime. Otherwise the overtime is equal to `hours - 80`, right?

You can express the logic in C++ like this:

```
float hours;
float overtime;

//....

cout<<"enter the amount of hours you have worked\n";
cin>>hours;

if(hours > 80)
{
    overtime = hours - 80;
}
else
{
    overtime = 0;
}
```

If you initialize the `overtime` variable to `0`, you can omit the `else` part.

```
float hours;
float overtime = 0;

//....

cout<<"enter the amount of hours you have worked\n";
cin>>hours;

if(hours > 80)
{
    overtime = hours - 80;
}
```

Comment: thank you for explaining this. I realize that my coding needs work and am working on cleaning this up and making it readable but thank all of you for your input it helps me better understand the logic.